# Spring Boot JPA Query on MySQL reads only the first row

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, jpa

I am facing a strange behaviour when reading a view from mysql.
My select statement is reading only the first row.

But it works fine when I read other db-tables.

Has someone an idea what it can be?

**This is my create statement:**

> CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY
> DEFINER VIEW `v_monthlyexpense` AS select distinct `_v`.`customerid`
> AS `customerid`,`_o`.`createddatetime` AS
> `createddatetime`,`_o`.`pricegross` AS `pricegross` from ((`c_visit`
> `_v` join `c_visit_order` `_vo` on(`_vo`.`visitId` = `_v`.`id`)) join
> `c_order` `_o` on(`_o`.`id` = `_vo`.`orderId`));

**This is my Entity:**

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name="v_monthlyexpense")
public class View_MonthlyExpense {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="customerid", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long customerId;

    @Column(name="createddatetime")
    private Timestamp createdDateTime;

    @Column(name="pricegross")
    private float priceGross;

    protected View_MonthlyExpense() {
    }

    public View_MonthlyExpense(Long customerId, Timestamp createdDateTime, float priceGross) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
        this.createdDateTime = createdDateTime;
        this.priceGross = priceGross;
    }

    public Long getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreatedDateTime() {
        return createdDateTime;
    }

    public float getPriceGross() {
        return priceGross;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return customerId + ". " + createdDateTime + " - " + priceGross + " USD";
    }
}
```

**This is my repository:**

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface ExpenseRepository2 extends CrudRepository<View_MonthlyExpense, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT e FROM View_MonthlyExpense e")
    public List<View_MonthlyExpense> findAll();
}
```

**This is my App:**

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ExpenseApp implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    ExpenseRepository2 repository2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExpenseApp.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        List<View_MonthlyExpense> list =  repository2.findAll();

        List<View_MonthlyExpense> iter = repository2.findAll();
        iter.forEach(item -> System.out.print(item + "\n"));
    }
}
```

**This is the output of the App:**

> 1002. 2021-11-24 22:38:55.0 - 8.0 USD
> 1003. 2021-11-24 22:38:55.0 - 8.0 USD
> 1004. 2021-11-24 22:38:55.0 - 8.0 USD
> 1005. 2021-11-24 22:38:55.0 - 8.0 USD
> 1006. 2021-11-24 22:38:55.0 - 8.0 USD
> 1007. 2021-11-24 22:38:55.0 - 8.0 USD
> 1008. 2021-11-24 22:38:55.0 - 8.0 USD
> 1009. 2021-11-26 23:17:03.0 - 12.0 USD
> 1010. 2021-11-26 23:17:03.0 - 12.0 USD
> 1011. 2021-11-26 23:17:03.0 - 12.0 USD
> 1012. 2021-11-26 23:17:03.0 - 12.0 USD
> 1013. 2021-11-26 23:17:03.0 - 12.0 USD
> 1014. 2021-11-26 23:17:03.0 - 12.0 USD
> 1015. 2021-11-26 23:17:03.0 - 12.0 USD
> 1016. 2021-11-26 23:17:03.0 - 12.0 USD
> 1017. 2021-11-26 23:17:03.0 - 12.0 USD

**And finally, this are the values in the database:**

```
customerId  createdDateTime     priceGross
1002        24.11.2021 22:38    8
1002        24.11.2021 22:38    10
1002        24.11.2021 22:38    6
1002        25.11.2021 00:46    6
1002        25.11.2021 00:46    10
1002        25.11.2021 00:46    11
1002        25.11.2021 00:46    15
1004        26.11.2021 23:17    12
1004        26.11.2021 23:17    8
1004        26.11.2021 23:17    10
1004        27.11.2021 02:06    12
1004        27.11.2021 02:06    8
1004        27.11.2021 02:06    6
1004        27.11.2021 02:06    30
1004        27.11.2021 02:06    15
1004        27.11.2021 02:06    50
```

**Here I post the values of the result in my debuger, this is before I use System.out.println:**

```
iter = {ArrayList@7390}  size = 16
 0 = {View_MonthlyExpense@7395} "1002. 2021-11-24 22:38:55.0 - 8.0 USD"
 1 = {View_MonthlyExpense@7395} "1002. 2021-11-24 22:38:55.0 - 8.0 USD"
 2 = {View_MonthlyExpense@7395} "1002. 2021-11-24 22:38:55.0 - 8.0 USD"
 3 = {View_MonthlyExpense@7395} "1002. 2021-11-24 22:38:55.0 - 8.0 USD"
 4 = {View_MonthlyExpense@7395} "1002. 2021-11-24 22:38:55.0 - 8.0 USD"
 5 = {View_MonthlyExpense@7395} "1002. 2021-11-24 22:38:55.0 - 8.0 USD"
 6 = {View_MonthlyExpense@7395} "1002. 2021-11-24 22:38:55.0 - 8.0 USD"
 7 = {View_MonthlyExpense@7396} "1004. 2021-11-26 23:17:03.0 - 12.0 USD"
 8 = {View_MonthlyExpense@7396} "1004. 2021-11-26 23:17:03.0 - 12.0 USD"
 9 = {View_MonthlyExpense@7396} "1004. 2021-11-26 23:17:03.0 - 12.0 USD"
 10 = {View_MonthlyExpense@7396} "1004. 2021-11-26 23:17:03.0 - 12.0 USD"
 11 = {View_MonthlyExpense@7396} "1004. 2021-11-26 23:17:03.0 - 12.0 USD"
 12 = {View_MonthlyExpense@7396} "1004. 2021-11-26 23:17:03.0 - 12.0 USD"
 13 = {View_MonthlyExpense@7396} "1004. 2021-11-26 23:17:03.0 - 12.0 USD"
 14 = {View_MonthlyExpense@7396} "1004. 2021-11-26 23:17:03.0 - 12.0 USD"
 15 = {View_MonthlyExpense@7396} "1004. 2021-11-26 23:17:03.0 - 12.0 USD"
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a Iterator you have to make a .hasNext() or .next() call for each row.

```
while(it.hasNext()) {
     System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Comment: For the result I am using a "List" not an Iterator.

Comment: I can see the values of iter in the debuger. Those are same as the outpout. This means, I recieve only the first row of each customerId.

Comment: Just as update. I have implemented seveal variations with always the same result. If I work with EntityManager and native sql, it works. If I use JPA and @Query I get only the first row. May some of you have an idea how it comes. Thnx.